# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS not booting from Hard drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, usb

I decided to get rid of windows and install Ubuntu 22.04 on the family computer. I think the versatility of Linux could be a good method to get the little one introduced to programming.

Though I'm facing a problem I don't know how to go about, and was hoping for some guidance or input on how to resolve my problem.

I have installed Ubuntu on the PC via the standard method (boot from USB etc), and deleted the partition for windows. I know have one partition that is solely for Ubuntu.

Though the machine does not see the boot file on the hard drive and only boots Ubuntu from the USB, despite having already installed. When I run `sudo fdisk -l` I get the following:

```
Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda2       1187840 975482180 974294341 464.6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Device       Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048     4095     2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sdb2     4096  1054719  1050624  513M EFI System
/dev/sdb3  1054720 30259199 29204480 13.9G Linux filesystem
```

As can be seen the linux file system (sdb3) is on the USB. I have already ran `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` and update grub, but doesnt seem to have done anything

Further more, after a lot of googling I ran the boot-repair with the following output, it looks like the PC still has Windows, while grub (if I understand correctly) is still looking at sdb where the usb is (?):

[boot-repair results](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/F9D6nP8qd6/)

How can I rectify this? any help would be appreciated

-------- EDIT --------

So the Installer used my USB stick as the location to unpack and install Ubuntu. I burnt another USB with the ISO file and seems to work nicely, the only problem is that upon PC boot I have to F9 it and instruct it to load fro UEFI every time. I'm gonna leave that on the back burner until I come back from Christmas - cheers everyone and thanks for your help! <3

Comment: What model HP? It shows Windows still in sda2 and no other partitions on sda. And the 16GB flash drive looks more like a full install, not a live installer anymore. Did you do a full  install over the live installer? You also need to know if UEFI or BIOS install and if drive is very old MBR or gpt partitioned. Your sda drive is MBR which would mean Windows was BIOS boot. But it now has no boot files which probably were in sda1, now missing.

Comment: To me it looks like you installed Ubuntu on the USB, not the PC.

Comment: The filesystem on sda should be ext4 and not a MS filesystem as shown. Boot sdb and reinstall Ubuntu to sda. What tool did you use to create the Live USB?

Comment: I have an elite HP notebook, wouldn't say that it is very old maybe a couple of years(?). Yeah and I dont know how I managed to do that, I used https://www.balena.io/etcher/ to burn the image on the usb stick, basicaly followed the ubuntu step by step guie..https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#3-create-a-bootable-usb-stick

Comment: You might check md5sums to confirm ISO is not corrupt. Perhaps try Ventoy for the installation this time.

Comment: My happy discovery today: using systemd-boot instead of grub. And suddenly, everything  works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Ubuntu on sda (your harddrive that is 500 Gb), not on sdb ( your usb stick that is 16 Gb).

Comment: yeah that is what I suspected, what do you think the best way forward is - possibly create another image on a usb stick and re- install Ubuntu?

Comment: That would be the best thing to do.